# How to build local docker image using python API with custom tag name

Tags: python, docker, docker-api

I have this script:

```
import docker
import os

localtag = "mypersonaltag"

client = docker.from_env()
dockerfile_path = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
print(dockerfile_path)

fname = dockerfile_path + "/Dockerfile"
path = os.path.dirname(fname)
image, build_log  = client.images.build(path=dockerfile_path, dockerfile='Dockerfile', tag='localtag', rm=True)
print(image)
```

If I execute this script, it creates and build local docker image with tag name as localtag, but not as 
mypersonaltag. I have tried all other possible way like below, have a look at tag parameter. and it's throwing error.

```
image, build_log  = client.images.build(path=dockerfile_path, dockerfile='Dockerfile', tag=localtag, rm=True)
```

or
    image, build_log  = client.images.build(path=dockerfile_path, dockerfile='Dockerfile', tag={localtag}, rm=True)

but the strange thing, this `[image, build_log  = client.images.build(path=dockerfile_path, dockerfile='Dockerfile', tag=localtag, rm=True)]` command works perfectly thru python editor while using python script it gives error. No idea why? But as soon as I give quotes around the tags the python script which was breaking now working fine.

```
>>> tag  = "test02"
>>> image, build_log  = client.images.build(path=path, dockerfile='Dockerfile', tag=tag, rm=True)
>>> print(image)
<Image: 'local_tag:latest', 'localtag:latest', 'test01:latest', 'test02:latest'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
image, build_log  = client.images.build(path=dockerfile_path, dockerfile='Dockerfile', tag=localtag, rm=True)
```

It's problem with passing variable to function, remove quotes around localtag

If you pass variable in such way `tag={localtag}`, then you are telling to python: "Hey take may variable, put it inside set, and pass this set to function". Probably you would try `f"{localtag}"` which uses fstring construction (requires python3.6).

`--edit--`

Please show us, how do you invoke your script? And what is the error?

Comment: if you look at my question, I tried this one in my script, it doesn't work or doesn't like quotes around my tag. without quotes it works fine with quotes it complains "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))" but odd enough, if I run the command in python editor it works like charm, >>> tag  = "test02"
>>> image, build_log  = client.images.build(path=path, dockerfile='Dockerfile', tag=tag, rm=True)>>> print(image)<Image: 'local_tag:latest', 'localtag:latest', 'test01:latest', 'test02:latest'>so, don't know why in editor it works.

Comment: `tag=localtag|{localtag}` - this construction is very very strange

Comment: now I understand, your confusion "|" this means I tried with both options without quotes and with curly braces. But more strange thing is it works fine in python editor but not via script.  I will update the question.

Comment: it's not working either. Please see below, I'm invoking python script using `python scriptname.py` and error I get with out quotes are `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))` and my python version is 2.7 so no fstring options. so something tells me tag with the quotes is giving me the problem in the script.

Comment: First of all, I strongly suggest you to switch to python3 (python2 is deprecated). Second show me version of your `docker-py` package - it may looks like error in your version `docker-py` : https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/978

Comment: At this moment, we are kind of bound with IT system so, no version 3 at this moment. :-( however this is docker python package version >>> print(docker.__version__)
4.1.0
>>>